# Specific right click functions + Web browser. Good Idea?

Tags: browser, save, copy-paste, right-click

I would create a web browser that can do specific functions by right clicking to thing.

But also, users might want to save an image, or copy something.

Is it worth killing the default menus for a silly little idea? Or should I implement the features to that "right click function"?

That may be a bad idea again, because the users might not find where is what.

Comment: Ithink you should give a try to your idea, as people rarely use the right click when browsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing default behaviour is never a good idea. We humans are creatures of habit, and changing our personal workflows will most likely result in more questions than answers (and the frustration that comes with that).

Adding to default behaviour might work, like adding a custom item in the context menu that is specifically for your own custom functions. But then you might also need to explain/show the user that it's actually there, or they will never be triggered to use this workflow.

Read more about custom context menus in the [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#context-menus).
But be aware of the lack of [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=contextmenu).